# I may not be a great writer, but i am a better writer

Tags: grammar

is that grammatically correct?

I think I am going to contradict myself. how would I state I may not be the best writer... but I have improved

Comment: What's wrong with: 'I may not be the best writer (in the world), but I have improved'? It’s grammatically correct and straight-forward

Comment: _I am a better write_ doesn't even make sense. Is that what you really meant to write, or did you get cut off? Please put the sentence you're asking about in the question, the title should be a summary of the question.

Comment: _but I am a better writer than I used to be_ would be OK as well.

Answer (score 3):

> I may not be a great writer, but I am getting better.

This conveys your intent with the least amount of changes to your sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

*I may not be a great writer, but **I know** I **am a better writer than yesterday**.*

Answer (score 0):

You can also say:

> I may not be the *best* writer, but I am a *better* writer.

Or

> I may not be the best writer but I can still get the point out there.